# UDF Function - does not recognize formula inside UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a function UDF in Excel where it is expected to have a value with length 2 or 4 characters. When it is two characters, it returns the same. If it is four, it should randomly select the two of the left or two at the right.

The problem is, when I want to use the formula **RandBetween** it does not recognize it (error: Sub Or Function not defined), however I am able to use it on a sub without any problem.

```
 Function SCountry(A As String)
        If Len(A) = 2 Then
            SCountry = A
        ElseIf Len(A) = 4 Then
            SCountry = Choose(RandBetween(1, 2), Left(A, 2), Right(A, 2)) Or Choose(1, Left(A, 2), Right(A, 2))
        Else
            SCountry = "Error"
        End If
End Function
```

What can be the problem? I tried everything and I did an extensive search but still not sure how to overcome this. A normal formula would not be a solution, because it would be too big, complicated and subject to change.

Comment: Not sure how you got it to work in a sub on its own without a problem - unless you use `Worksheetfunction.Randbetween(1,2)`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and make it a habit that you pass every parameter to a Sub/Function as **ByVal**, e.g. `SCountry(ByVal A As String)` _unless_ you want to change the value of that parameter **and** work with the changed value in the _calling_ code. You safe yourself from changing values by accident that way. See the [ByVal docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byval) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! worksheetfunction. worked and I will use onwards ByVal! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

### A Random UDF

```vb
Option Explicit

Function SCountry(ByVal S As String) As String
        
        Select Case Len(S)
        Case 2
            SCountry = S
        Case 4
            SCountry = IIf(Application.RandBetween(-1, 0), _
                Left(S, 2), Right(S, 2))
        Case Else
            SCountry = "Error"
        End Select

End Function
```